# is there a HAL_SPI_transmit function in stm8?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, spi, stm8

I'm trying to write a stm32 code in stm8. The problem is I can't find a SPI_Transmit function only SPI_SendData. I need this function to transmit an array through SPI.
The stm32 SPI_transmit function looks like this:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SPI_Transmit(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
{
  uint32_t tickstart;
  HAL_StatusTypeDef errorcode = HAL_OK;
  uint16_t initial_TxXferCount;

  /* Check Direction parameter */
  assert_param(IS_SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES_OR_1LINE(hspi->Init.Direction));

  /* Process Locked */
  __HAL_LOCK(hspi);

  /* Init tickstart for timeout management*/
  tickstart = HAL_GetTick();
  initial_TxXferCount = Size;

  if (hspi->State != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY)
  {
    errorcode = HAL_BUSY;
    goto error;
  }

  if ((pData == NULL) || (Size == 0U))
  {
    errorcode = HAL_ERROR;
    goto error;
  }

  /* Set the transaction information */
  hspi->State       = HAL_SPI_STATE_BUSY_TX;
  hspi->ErrorCode   = HAL_SPI_ERROR_NONE;
  hspi->pTxBuffPtr  = (uint8_t *)pData;
  hspi->TxXferSize  = Size;
  hspi->TxXferCount = Size;

  /*Init field not used in handle to zero */
  hspi->pRxBuffPtr  = (uint8_t *)NULL;
  hspi->RxXferSize  = 0U;
  hspi->RxXferCount = 0U;
  hspi->TxISR       = NULL;
  hspi->RxISR       = NULL;

  /* Configure communication direction : 1Line */
  if (hspi->Init.Direction == SPI_DIRECTION_1LINE)
  {
    /* Disable SPI Peripheral before set 1Line direction (BIDIOE bit) */
    __HAL_SPI_DISABLE(hspi);
    SPI_1LINE_TX(hspi);
  }

#if (USE_SPI_CRC != 0U)
  /* Reset CRC Calculation */
  if (hspi->Init.CRCCalculation == SPI_CRCCALCULATION_ENABLE)
  {
    SPI_RESET_CRC(hspi);
  }
#endif /* USE_SPI_CRC */

  /* Check if the SPI is already enabled */
  if ((hspi->Instance->CR1 & SPI_CR1_SPE) != SPI_CR1_SPE)
  {
    /* Enable SPI peripheral */
    __HAL_SPI_ENABLE(hspi);
  }

  /* Transmit data in 16 Bit mode */
  if (hspi->Init.DataSize == SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT)
  {
    if ((hspi->Init.Mode == SPI_MODE_SLAVE) || (initial_TxXferCount == 0x01U))
    {
      hspi->Instance->DR = *((uint16_t *)hspi->pTxBuffPtr);
      hspi->pTxBuffPtr += sizeof(uint16_t);
      hspi->TxXferCount--;
    }
    /* Transmit data in 16 Bit mode */
    while (hspi->TxXferCount > 0U)
    {
      /* Wait until TXE flag is set to send data */
      if (__HAL_SPI_GET_FLAG(hspi, SPI_FLAG_TXE))
      {
        hspi->Instance->DR = *((uint16_t *)hspi->pTxBuffPtr);
        hspi->pTxBuffPtr += sizeof(uint16_t);
        hspi->TxXferCount--;
      }
      else
      {
        /* Timeout management */
        if ((((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart) >=  Timeout) && (Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)) || (Timeout == 0U))
        {
          errorcode = HAL_TIMEOUT;
          goto error;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  /* Transmit data in 8 Bit mode */
  else
  {
    if ((hspi->Init.Mode == SPI_MODE_SLAVE) || (initial_TxXferCount == 0x01U))
    {
      *((__IO uint8_t *)&hspi->Instance->DR) = (*hspi->pTxBuffPtr);
      hspi->pTxBuffPtr += sizeof(uint8_t);
      hspi->TxXferCount--;
    }
    while (hspi->TxXferCount > 0U)
    {
      /* Wait until TXE flag is set to send data */
      if (__HAL_SPI_GET_FLAG(hspi, SPI_FLAG_TXE))
      {
        *((__IO uint8_t *)&hspi->Instance->DR) = (*hspi->pTxBuffPtr);
        hspi->pTxBuffPtr += sizeof(uint8_t);
        hspi->TxXferCount--;
      }
      else
      {
        /* Timeout management */
        if ((((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart) >=  Timeout) && (Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)) || (Timeout == 0U))
        {
          errorcode = HAL_TIMEOUT;
          goto error;
        }
      }
    }
  }
#if (USE_SPI_CRC != 0U)
  /* Enable CRC Transmission */
  if (hspi->Init.CRCCalculation == SPI_CRCCALCULATION_ENABLE)
  {
    SET_BIT(hspi->Instance->CR1, SPI_CR1_CRCNEXT);
  }
#endif /* USE_SPI_CRC */

  /* Check the end of the transaction */
  if (SPI_EndRxTxTransaction(hspi, Timeout, tickstart) != HAL_OK)
  {
    hspi->ErrorCode = HAL_SPI_ERROR_FLAG;
  }

  /* Clear overrun flag in 2 Lines communication mode because received is not read */
  if (hspi->Init.Direction == SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES)
  {
    __HAL_SPI_CLEAR_OVRFLAG(hspi);
  }

  if (hspi->ErrorCode != HAL_SPI_ERROR_NONE)
  {
    errorcode = HAL_ERROR;
  }

error:
  hspi->State = HAL_SPI_STATE_READY;
  /* Process Unlocked */
  __HAL_UNLOCK(hspi);
  return errorcode;
}
```

This is what the SPI_SendData function looks like:

```
void SPI_SendData(SPI_TypeDef* SPIx, uint8_t Data)
{
  SPIx->DR = Data; /* Write in the DR register the data to be sent*/
}
```

Stm8 doesn't have HAL functions. I think I have to define a completely new function for this to work in stm8, but I'm not sure. Is there another way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Please [edit] your question and show us the prototype and description of `SPI_SendData()`. Please add why you think you cannot use it instead of `HAL_SPI_Transmit()`.

Comment: It is hardly rocket science to call `SPI_SendData()` iteratively is it?  Send data, wait for TXE, repeat.  Sometimes in programming you have to, you know, program stuff. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> I think I have to define a completely new function for this to work in stm8, but I'm not sure.

Yes very likely a completely new function/driver. STM8 is an entirely different architecture compared to STM32. If you are lucky some STM8 hardware peripherals were re-used in STM32, but I doubt it since STM8 is a way older legacy architecture. For example I would guess that it only supports 8 bit mode (which is the common implementation).

The way to actually learn microcontroller programming proper, is to learn how to write drivers yourself instead of relying on various bloatware libs such as the horrible, so-called "HAL" by ST.

SPI is an excellent peripheral to use when practicing this, since it is relatively simple hardware. Some tricky things to look out for:

- SPI does not transmit or receive, it *transceives* in full duplex.
- Flag clearing in SPI peripherals is often done automatically, for example by reading a status register followed by reading a data register. This can sometimes mess up debuggers that display registers or a raw memory map, since the debugger might get the idea to read registers when you single step and thereby destroy the flags.
- /SS chip select might sometimes be handled by the SPI hardware, sometimes you have to handle it manually with GPIO. Also some devices might have peculiar timing requirements forcing you to handle things manually.

You can tailor the driver for a specific application or make it more generic, at your own preference.